# Google protobuf compiling for Netframework 4.0

Tags: .net-4.0, protocol-buffers, .net-framework-version

According to the [documentation](https://github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf/tree/master/csharp) protobuf can be compiled for legacy netframework versions down to 3.5. I followed the instructions and added net40 as an additional targetframework after installing the google-protobuf via nuget.

Unfortunately there is still the dependency `System.Memory (4.5.2)` which can not be satisfied by
< net45. When removing this dependency one can see that it can take much effort to use alternative datastructures.

Are there additional steps required to compile for `net40` or is the documentation not up to date ?
Furthermore I can not infer from the tags which version might compile for `net40`

Comment: Were you able to resolve the issue?